# Jquery Accordion from Scratch is jerky

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, accordion, css-selectors

I am trying to build an accordion from scratch. Here are my issues.

Question #1:
However how do I use the "nth child" property to show the first section of slidetext?

Question #2:
How do I optimize my Jquery code such instead of having everything slideup each time the mouseenter event is called, I can check to see which sections are open, then slideup only that open section??
Right now its very jerky and the footer is sliding up creating a very jerky effect.

JS:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var slidetext=$('.slide_text');
    var box=$('.box');
    slidetext.addClass('hide');
    $('#content').on('mouseenter','.slide_header', function () {
<!--     $slidetext.addClass('hide'); -->
     slidetext.slideUp(200);
    box.removeClass('boxlight');
     $(this).find(box).addClass('boxlight');
      $(this).next().slideDown(200);
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id ="container_wrap">
  <div id ="header_wrap">
    <div id = "header">
      <div class = "logo"> </div>
      <div class = "search">
        <input type=search name=s>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id ="content_wrap">
    <div id ="container">
      <div id = "navbar">
        <ul>
          <li>home</li>
          <li>about us</li>
          <li>services</li>
          <li>contact us</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id = "content">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
        <h2> Some Kind of Subheading About Whatever This Is</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce dui diam, tempor nec tempor id, sollicitudin facilisis ligula. Sed accumsan luctus sem, non malesuada nisi porttitor at. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi tristique, nunc a mollis iaculis, lorem quam mollis nulla, a pretium augue leo nec arcu. Curabitur sodales pharetra sem, id volutpat nisi semper vitae. Proin erat diam, laoreet vel pretium vitae, mattis vel ipsum. Morbi euismod suscipit dui. Maecenas gravida ultrices magna sed feugiat. </p>
        <div class = "slide">
          <div class = "slide_header">
            <h3>Some Section Title 1</h3>
            <div class = "box">
              <p>-</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class = "slide_text">
            <p>Donec massa enim, tempor id fringilla sit amet, ultrices in ante. In sagittis lectus eu risus dignissim bibendum. Mauris in pretium enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse lobortis, lectus vel semper imperdiet, est risus faucibus purus, et ultrices orci metus non arcu. Aliquam iaculis congue volutpat. Sed ac massa dui. Mauris dapibus mollis sem vel adipiscing. Aliquam quam eros, pulvinar eu dapibus non, tempor vitae orci. Cras suscipit viverra felis et mattis. 
              Donec massa enim, tempor id fringilla sit amet, ultrices in ante. In sagittis lectus eu risus dignissim bibendum. Mauris in pretium enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse lobortis, lectus vel semper imperdiet, est risus faucibus purus, et ultrices orci metus non arcu. Aliquam iaculis congue volutpat. Sed ac massa dui. Mauris dapibus mollis sem vel adipiscing. Aliquam quam eros, pulvinar eu dapibus non, tempor vitae orci. Cras suscipit viverra felis et mattis. 
              Donec massa enim, tempor id fringilla sit amet, ultrices in ante. In sagittis lectus eu risus dignissim bibendum. Mauris in pretium enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse lobortis, lectus vel semper imperdiet, est risus faucibus purus, et ultrices orci metus non arcu. Aliquam iaculis congue volutpat. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "slide">
          <div class = "slide_header">
            <h3>Some Section Title 1</h3>
            <div class = "box">
              <p>-</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class = "slide_text">
            <p>Donec massa enim, tempor id fringilla sit amet, ultrices in ante. In sagittis lectus eu risus dignissim bibendum. Mauris in pretium enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse lobortis, lectus vel semper imperdiet, est risus faucibus purus, et ultrices orci metus non arcu. Aliquam iaculis congue volutpat. Sed ac massa dui. Mauris dapibus mollis sem vel adipiscing. Aliquam quam eros, pulvinar eu dapibus non, tempor vitae orci. Cras suscipit viverra felis et mattis. 
              Donec massa enim, tempor id fringilla sit amet, ultrices in ante. In sagittis lectus eu risus dignissim bibendum. Mauris in pretium enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse lobortis, lectus vel semper imperdiet, est risus faucibus purus, et ultrices orci metus non arcu. Aliquam iaculis congue volutpat. Sed ac massa dui. Mauris dapibus mollis sem vel adipiscing. Aliquam quam eros, pulvinar eu dapibus non, tempor vitae orci. Cras suscipit viverra felis et mattis. 
              Donec massa enim, tempor id fringilla sit amet, ultrices in ante. In sagittis lectus eu risus dignissim bibendum. Mauris in pretium enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse lobortis, lectus vel semper imperdiet, est risus faucibus purus, et ultrices orci metus non arcu. Aliquam iaculis congue volutpat. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "slide">
          <div class = "slide_header">
            <h3>Some Section Title 1</h3>
            <div class = "box">
              <p>-</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class = "slide_text">
            <p>Donec massa enim, tempor id fringilla sit amet, ultrices in ante. In sagittis lectus eu risus dignissim bibendum. Mauris in pretium enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse lobortis, lectus vel semper imperdiet, est risus faucibus purus, et ultrices orci metus non arcu. Aliquam iaculis congue volutpat. Sed ac massa dui. Mauris dapibus mollis sem vel adipiscing. Aliquam quam eros, pulvinar eu dapibus non, tempor vitae orci. Cras suscipit viverra felis et mattis. 
              Donec massa enim, tempor id fringilla sit amet, ultrices in ante. In sagittis lectus eu risus dignissim bibendum. Mauris in pretium enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse lobortis, lectus vel semper imperdiet, est risus faucibus purus, et ultrices orci metus non arcu. Aliquam iaculis congue volutpat. Sed ac massa dui. Mauris dapibus mollis sem vel adipiscing. Aliquam quam eros, pulvinar eu dapibus non, tempor vitae orci. Cras suscipit viverra felis et mattis. 
              Donec massa enim, tempor id fringilla sit amet, ultrices in ante. In sagittis lectus eu risus dignissim bibendum. Mauris in pretium enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse lobortis, lectus vel semper imperdiet, est risus faucibus purus, et ultrices orci metus non arcu. Aliquam iaculis congue volutpat. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id = "foot_wrap">
    <div id = "footer">
      <div class = "copy">
        <p> &#169;2013 LOGO.</p>
      </div>
      <div id = "foot_bar">
        <ul>
          <li>home </li>
          <li>|</li>
          <li>about us </li>
          <li>|</li>
          <li>services</li>
          <li>|</li>
          <li>contact us</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#container_wrap {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#000000;
}
#content_wrap {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    border-bottom:black 1px solid;
    box-shadow: 4px 2px 4px 2px #ccc;
    -webkit-border-shadow: 4px 2px 4px 2px #ccc;
    -moz-border-shadow: 4px 2px 4px 2px #ccc;
}
#container {
    width:935px;
    margin:auto;
}

/* header and logo*/

#header_wrap {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    height:100px;
}
#header, #navbar, #content {
    width:935px;
    margin:auto;
}
#content {
    float:left;
}
.logo {
    float:left;
    background:url(images/logo.png);
    width:202px;
    height:53px;
    background-position:top left;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

input[type=search] { 
       color: #FF0000;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000000;
    width: 100px;
    word-spacing: 20px;             
}
/* header and logo*/

/* nav bar*/

#navbar {
    float:left;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#navbar ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    height:35px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-left:0px;
}
#navbar ul li {
    float:left;
    color:#1da7dd;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding: 9px 35px;
    font-size:18px;
}
#navbar ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
#navbar ul li:hover, #nav ul li a:hover {
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#000;
    height:26px;
}
/* nav bar*/



/* content*/
#content h1 {
    font-size:32px;
    color:#404040;
}
#content h2 {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#1da7dd;
}
#content p {
    font-size:12px;
}
.slide {
}
.slide_header {
    background:#404040;
    background: rgb(69,72,77); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(69, 72, 77, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(69, 72, 77, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(69, 72, 77, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(69, 72, 77, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(69, 72, 77, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(69, 72, 77, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#45484d', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    float: left;
    width: 935px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-bottom:white 1px solid;
    height: 30px;
}
.slide_header h3 {
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:tahoma;
    color:white;
    margin: 7px 0 0;
    float:left;
}
.box {
    float:right;
    background-color:#999999;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}

.boxlight {
background-color:#00FF99;

}

#slide_header p {
    float:right;
    color:white;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size:30px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.slide_text {
    float:left;
}
.slide_text p {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color:#5e5e5e;
    line-height:1.4em;
}

/* content*/

/* footer*/

#footer {
    font-size:12px;
    width: 935px;
    margin:auto;
}
#footer .copy {
    float:left;
}
#foot_bar {
    float:right;
}
#foot_bar ul {
    float:right;
}
#foot_bar ul li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-left:10px;
}
#foot_wrap {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#dddddd;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
}
/* footer*/

.hide {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide all slides except for the first:

```
slidetext.not(':first').addClass('hide');
```

To make animation less jerky, try stopping the animation before sliding:

```
slidetext.stop().slideUp(200);
...
$(this).next().stop().slideDown(200);
```